# Debug long compile times in Scala and SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

In my Scala/SBT project, I have one file that takes up to 5(!) minutes to compile.  All the other ones can compile in a few seconds.  This makes development pretty painful.

I'm sure that I'm abusing some Scala constructs, but I have no idea how to go about debugging it.  How does one debug long compile times in Scala?

I'm using Scala 2.9.2 and SBT 0.11.2

Comment: Long compile times can have many reasons. Without posting the code, I doubt that you will get much help. A first step might be to split the file into several ones and see which parts take longest to compile. That also helps with _re_compilation times.

Comment: I can't break up the file without refactoring a lot of code, since it only contains one class.  I'm more interested in seeing if there is some flag I can turn on in the compiler that can give me more hints as to where the problem is.

Comment: Fair enough, but you can split the class into traits without touching the rest of the code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try the following Scala compiler options:

- `-Ystatistics`                   Print compiler statistics

Find a phase that takes the most time. Then, try those:

- `-Xprint:<phase>`                Print out program after  or "all"
- `-Yshow-trees`                   Show detailed trees when used in connection with -print:phase
- `-Ydebug`                        Output debugging messages
- `-Ypmat-debug`                   Trace all pattern matcher activity.

To enable these settings directly from the sbt console, you can use `set scalacOptions in ThisBuild += "-Ystatistics"`, or for more than one, `set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-Yshow-trees", "-Ydebug")`