# Scala macro compilation times

Tags: scala, compilation, macros, shapeless, circe

Working on a scala project that uses libraries such as circe, enumeratum, and shapeless

We have a few enums defined namely, Region; EntityType and EntityAction
eg

```
sealed trait EntityAction extends EnumEntry with Hyphencase

case object EntityAction extends Enum[EntityAction] with CirceEnum[EntityAction] {
  //noinspection ScalaStyle
  case object * extends EntityAction

  case object CreateUser extends EntityAction
  ... omitted ...
}
```

We also have a Permission model defined as

```
case class Permission(
                   resource: EntityType,
                   regions: Set[Region],
                   actions: Set[EntityAction],
                   instances: Set[String]
                 )
```

We also have an UserEntityModel (that is saved in our data store in a json format) and a UserModel that is returned as part of the http response

```
case class UserEntityV1(
                     override val entityKey: EntityKey,
                     firstName: String,
                     lastName: String,
                     override val email: String,
                     override val permissions: Set[Permission],
                     override val revokedPermissions: Set[Permission],
                     override val status: EntityStatus
                     ...

           ) extends UserEntity
```

EntityKey contains the Region enum and the omitted fields are of non enum types

```
case class User(
             override val uuid: Option[String] = None,
             firstName: String,
             lastName: String,
             email: String,
             status: EntityStatus,
             permissions: Set[Permission],
             revokedPermissions: Set[Permission]
             ...
           ) extends HasPayload
```

Without the permissions and revokedPermissions from the UserEntity and the User model, the `clean compile` time is under 3 minutes. With those fields included, the compiler runs into

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:201)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.fullNameInSig$1(Erasure.scala:261)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.classSig$1(Erasure.scala:292)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.jsig$1(Erasure.scala:336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.boxedSig$1(Erasure.scala:243)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.argSig$1(Erasure.scala:281)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.$anonfun$javaSig$8(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.classSig$1(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.jsig$1(Erasure.scala:336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.boxedSig$1(Erasure.scala:243)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.argSig$1(Erasure.scala:281)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.$anonfun$javaSig$8(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.classSig$1(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.jsig$1(Erasure.scala:336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.boxedSig$1(Erasure.scala:243)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.argSig$1(Erasure.scala:281)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.$anonfun$javaSig$8(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.classSig$1(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.jsig$1(Erasure.scala:336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.boxedSig$1(Erasure.scala:243)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.argSig$1(Erasure.scala:281)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.$anonfun$javaSig$8(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.classSig$1(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.jsig$1(Erasure.scala:336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.boxedSig$1(Erasure.scala:243)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.argSig$1(Erasure.scala:281)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.$anonfun$javaSig$8(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.classSig$1(Erasure.scala:295)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.jsig$1(Erasure.scala:336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.jsig$1(Erasure.scala:359)
```

We solved it by defining a .sbtopts 
played around with a few variations of it , as it stands the current .sbtopts is

```
-J-Xms1024M
-J-Xmx4G
-J-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256M
-J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M
-J-Xss2M
```

played around with diff Xss values as well as specifying -mem , does not seem to make much of a diff.

However, with those fields included, the `clean compile` time average is now almost 7 minutes (as the user entity is used in a few places)

All indications point to macro compilation. We are using auto derivation. Is there a way to keep things boilerplate free and keep the type safety of the enums but reduce the compile time.

Current versions are

```
scala version =  2.12.1
sbt version = 0.13.13 
circeVersion = "0.7.0"
enumeratumVersion = "1.5.10"
enumeratumCirceVersion = "1.5.10"
shapelessVersion = "2.3.2"
```

On updating to the latest versions of the library and scala 2.12.3, the compile time jumps to almost 20 minutes

Tried following some steps from [debugging slow compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920661/debug-long-compile-times-in-scala-and-sbt)

As far as I can keep the its the typer phase

Comment: what .sbtopts are you using?

Comment: @StephenCarman I have updated the original post with the .sbtopts. Played around with a few different options, I know this following example is java `https://github.com/lagom/activator-lagom-java` but i used that as a starting point

Comment: I meant that I used the .sbtopts from that as a starting point, not for the whole project, also had a look at `https://medium.com/@jan______/sbtconfig-is-deprecated-650d6ff10236` and `https://github.com/miguno/kafka-storm-starter/blob/develop/.sbtopts`. I did have `-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` in my .sbtopts file at some point as well

Comment: Have you tried annotating classes you need JSON-ified with `@JsonCodec` ?

Comment: I changed the full auto derviation from using `import io.circe.generic.auto._` to use `@JsonCodec` instead. It has sped up the compile time by a bit. Still need to do a few more iterations to get an average. Had to change a few things in the code to make it compile. It might have pointed to the possible culprit. I am using circes `withDiscriminator("typ")` from the circes extras. and using @jsonCodec breaks the discriminator column which is no longer being written out to my json. And I have to specify the actual entity class instead of the sealed trait that it inherits from in a few places.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov so I had to use the `@ConfiguredJsonCodec` annotation to fix the discriminator being broken but looks like going away from full auto derivation has fixed the compilation time issues. `clean compile` seems to be under a minute now. Thanks!!